# Call parent function in xcode iphone development

Tags: iphone, function, delegates, parent

We have 2 files 'MainViewController' and 'View01'
The first file addSubView the second one.

In the first file we have a function named displayView.

I want to be able to call this function from the View01 file is the following code correct

part of View01 file

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

- (IBAction) changeView:id(sender){
      MainViewControlle *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      [appDelegate displayView:2];
}
```

is this the correct way to do it?

at the moment I use the NSNotificationCenter to send activate the functions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using delegate methods :-)

It works like that :

```
// Delegate
@protocol MyViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myViewAskedForSomethingWithOrWithoutParameters;

@end
```

In your view you must have this parameter :

```
id<MyViewDelegate>  delegate;
```

And then in your Controller you must implement the delegate

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <MyViewDelegate> {
}
```

In your implementation you need to add a :

```
myView.delegate = self;
```

And finally in your view when you need to call the function, just do :

```
[ delegate myViewAskedForSomethingWithOrWithoutParameters ];
```

Good Luck !

Comment: I see. any good tutorial on protocol?? :) thanks both of you for your answers

Comment: Just google it : http://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+protocol+delegate :-) first answers should be good ! like http://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+protocol+delegate

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, your code shouldn't work. Did you try it your self?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate]
```

will return your AppDelegate, called something like `MyAppDelegate` and not `MainViewController`. However, depending on the template you used or created, your AppDelegate might contain a MainViewController-property, most likely called `viewController` so you could use

```
 [appDelegate.viewController displayView:2];
```

This is the quick way to do it. For a more tidy way, see Vinzius' answer.